# HTML Bootstrap tab-content link in Nested List-group 'freezes' after first click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap nested list-group to build a page navigation feature on my HTML page.

When a user clicks `Home` the webpage should load `Link 1`, when a user clicks `Profile` the webpage should load `Link 2`.

When a user then clicks `Link 1` the webpage should load `Page 1`, and when a user clicks `Link 2` the webpage should load `Page 2`.

However the links (`link 1, link 2`) inside the div id `nav-tabContent` only work on first click.

On second click, the links 'freeze' and won't work unless I refresh the page.

Could someone please help me to spot where the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

The page UI looks like below.

[image]

The Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
        <a id="list-home-page" data-toggle="list" href="#aa" role="tab" aria-controls="a">
        Link 1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
        <a id="list-profile-page" data-toggle="list" href="#bb" role="tab" aria-controls="b">
        Link 2
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabPage">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="aa" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-page">
       Page 1
      </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bb" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-page">
       Page 2
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the first `tab-content` element inside the `col-8` element, but the second one outside of it? Can't imagine that to make much sense.

Comment: Sorry am new to bootstrap. So what would you suggest.

Comment: That you fix your HTL structure first of all, and put the second tab-content actually into col-8

Comment: The issue persists, even after I make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting them all in the same `tab-content` container, and then nest it further, and also wrapping links into a `list-group`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 ">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                <div class="list-group" role="tablist">
                    <a id="list-home" data-toggle="list" href="#aa" role="tab" aria-controls="a">Link 1        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabPage">
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="aa" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-page">
                        Page 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
                <div class="list-group" role="tablist">
                    <a id="list-profile" data-toggle="list" href="#bb" role="tab" aria-controls="b">    Link 2        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="bb" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-page">
                        Page 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```